# C#で乱数を重複せずに取り出す方法について

Tags: c#

C#で配列に格納された0から9までの数字を重複せずにランダムに取り出して別の配列に格納したいのですが、何か方法はありますか？

Comment: もしかして行いたいことは[シャッフル](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%BC%E2%80%93%E3%82%A4%E3%82%A7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%84%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%83%E3%83%95%E3%83%AB)ではありませんか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linqを使った2Liner版です。
手軽にランダムな配列を作成することができます。
ただしソート用の`random.Next()`に同値が入った場合にはソート前の配列順に並ぶため、完全にランダムな並び替えにはなりません。
例えば`src`の0が1より前に配置される確率は約0.0000000000000002%高くなります。
[Random.NextDoubleの備考を参照](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.random.nextdouble%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
この特性を踏まえて、ほぼランダムな配列を作成したい時のみご利用ください。

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var src = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
            //ランダムな別の配列作成
            var random = new Random();
            var dest = src.OrderBy(x => random.NextDouble()).ToArray();
            //結果表示
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", dest));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int[] ary = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

System.Random rng = new System.Random();
int n = ary.Length;
while (n > 1)
{
    n--;
    int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
    int tmp = ary[k];
    ary[k] = ary[n];
    ary[n] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: これが[フィッシャー–イェーツのシャッフル](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%BC%E2%80%93%E3%82%A4%E3%82%A7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%84%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%83%E3%83%95%E3%83%AB)(の正しい実装)であることを示されるとよりよいと思いました。結構間違った実装が公開されていることも多いようですし。